# php multilanguage menu for a website not working as expected

Tags: php

I created this code, but obviously it's not working. I feel there is a mistake somewhere in the logic but I don't see it.

```
`<?php
$languages = array(
    "en" => array("name" => "English", "selector" => "/en/", "image" => "en.png"),
    "fr" => array("name" => "French", "selector" => "/fr/", "image" => "fr.png"),
    "de" => array("name" => "German", "selector" => "/de/", "image" => "de.png"),
    "it" => array("name" => "Italian", "selector" => "/it/", "image" => "it.png"),
    "si" => array("name" => "Slovene", "selector" => "/si/", "image" => "si.png"),
    "es" => array("name" => "Spain", "selector" => "/es/", "image" => "es.png")
);

$current_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$current_language = "";

foreach ($languages as $code => $language) {
    if (strpos($current_url, $language['selector']) === 0) {
        $current_language = $code;
        break;
    }
}
?>

<div id="language-menu">
    <ul>
        <?php
        foreach($languages as $code => $language){
            $new_url = str_replace($languages[$current_language]['selector'], $language['selector'], $current_url);
            if($code === $current_language){
                echo '<li class="active">'.$language['name'].'</li>';
            } else {
                echo '<li><a href="'.$new_url.'">'.$language['name'].'</a></li>';
            }
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>`
```

I expect to have a browsing between different version of the same page, where I don't know the url and the name of the page itself

Comment: Start with just your top section only and make sure it is behaving how you expect: https://3v4l.org/BpIqj

Comment: No, it's not working as expected. It detect en when I'm on the FR, IT, ES and SI language for instance....

Comment: You'll need to inspect `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` then